# Is it possible to read Google+ username from PHP without Authentication?

Tags: php, google-plus

I'd like my web page to say "Welcome, [Google+ name here]!"
and so I've been looking around for a solution and checking whether or not it is possible to do it without asking him/her to log my website through Google+.

Looking around for it I found some libs:

```
  require_once 'google-api-php-client/apiClient.php';
  require_once 'google-api-php-client/contrib/apiOauth2Service.php';
```

Are these useful to my purposes? And the main question is: is what I wanna do possible (tips?)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I sincerely hope this is not possible. You will have to ask the user to allow your site to read their credentials.

Comment: How do you intend to get their usernames? I mean how do you know what their username is?

Comment: Google+ won't give you that information about a user, without the user signing in first and allowing your site to read that information. The libs you found are used to authenticate a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that isn't possible. If you want to know who the user is, you'll have to have them provide access to that information via sign-in or with an OAuth scope that allows you to query for their basic profile information.